# What's the best way to perform COUNT and PERCENTAGE in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 3 fieldnames, Age, Gender, and Agreed.

Agreed has 2 types of values - Agreed and Not Agreed.

What I would like to do is get a COUNT and % of age and gender who agreed as well as COUNT and % of age and gender with Not Agreed values.

We would like the layout to be something like:

```
AGE           GENDER            AGREED
93 600  40%   Female 700 62%   Agreed
   1300 60%          320 38%   Not Agreed
```

First, please bear in mind that I just made up the numbers but from the sample above, I am trying to show what layout we would like to have.

Each age would have 2 sets of values. A COUNT of those who agreed and their percentage *and* a COUNT of those who have NOT Agreed value and their percent.

Same with gender.

I hope this isn't confusing.

Below is the code I am working with but believe I am on the wrong track.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Select gender, age, agreed, count(agreed)totalAgreed,Agreed = convert(VARCHAR,convert(MONEY,100.0 * count(agreed) /(SELECT count(agreed) FROM   myTable)), 1) + '%' 

From myTable
Group By gender, age, agreed
```

Comment: you can't do percentages at the row level in a standard simple query, because that requires knowing totals which won't be available until the entire query has been processed. You'd need to nest queries or do it in two stages - do your counts to get totals, then re-query to do the percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to aggregate by gender and age to get the counts.  You can use conditional aggregations for what you want.  The following query gets the counts and the percentages as numbers.

```
select gender, age, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(case when agreed = 'Agreed' then 1 else 0 end) as NumAgreed,
       sum(case when agreed = 'NotAgreed' then 1 else 0 end) as NotAgreed,
       avg(case when agreed = 'Agreed' then 1.0 else 0 end) as NumAgreedRatio,
       avg(case when agreed = 'NotAgreed' then 1.0 else 0 end) as NotAgreedRatio
from myTable
group by gender, age
```

The form is a bit different from your desired table.  Does this also work?  Also, I didn't bother to convert the numbers to percents, since I like keeping numbers as numbers.

Comment: thank you very much @NYCdotNet and Gordon.

Gordon, your solution isn't right at all.

First, the NumagreedRatio and NotAgreedRatio are all 0.000.  Second, no groupings. I suppose I can add that.

NYCdotNet, your solution is closer but is there a way to show the groups closer to each other?

For instance, it will be nicer and clearer if for instance, we show gender of agreed and notagreed next to each other.

Eg, I added a fieldname called Race and the values are scattered.

It will be nice to show blacks who agreed and those who did not agree next to it.

Comment: My apologies @Gordon. Your solution is fine.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cc6d/9

```
--Returns count of agreed by gender:
SELECT Gender, Agreed, COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM MyTable GROUP BY Agreed, Gender;

--Returns count of agreed overall:
SELECT Agreed, COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM MyTable GROUP BY Agreed;

--Returns count of agreed by gender with percentages
With Overall as (SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) as [Count] FROM MyTable)
    SELECT mt.Gender, mt.Agreed, COUNT(*) as [Count], CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / o.Count as [Percentage]
FROM MyTable mt
    CROSS JOIN Overall o
GROUP BY mt.Agreed, mt.Gender, o.Count;
```

This should get you started.

If you want to pivot the data set into a single row, you can either handle that in your presentation layer, manually do subselects for each column, or else use the PIVOT feature of SQL which you can learn about here: http://nycdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/07/pattern-for-pivot.html